# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getAttributes does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I want certain fields that I don't want to be returned to me in the excel sheet.

The error is `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getAttributes does not exist.`in line `$attributes = $customer->getAttributes();`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\CustomerModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;

class CustomerExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{
    protected $id;

    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        $customer = CustomerModel::find($this->id);

        // Define the excluded attributes
        $excludeAttributes = ['id', 'column1', 'column2'];

        // Get all attributes except the excluded ones
        $attributes = $customer->getAttributes();
        $filteredAttributes = array_diff_key($attributes, array_flip($excludeAttributes));

        // Wrap the filtered attributes into a collection
        $collection = collect([$filteredAttributes]);

        return $collection;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Name',
            'Age',
            'Height',
            'Weight',
        ];
    }
}
```

- `CustomerModel.php`

```
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class CustomerModel extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $table = "customers";
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';
        
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'age',
            'height',
            'weight',
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Is CustomerModel an Eloquent model or is it a repository? Can you show the definition for CustomerModel?

Comment: CustomerModel is correct.

Comment: post the code of CustomerModel class in question

Comment: Can you show it? `find()` should return a single model, but according to the error, `$customer` is a collection instead.

Comment: `find` can return a single Model, a Collection of Models, or `null` ... you are passing an array (or `Arrayable`) to `find` it would seem ... you will need to debug to see what `$this->id` is and why it isn't a single scalar value as you seem to be expecting

Comment: @KavanPrajapati i posted the class Customermodel in my question.

Comment: That edit doesn't clear anything up... `$id` (and by execution, `$this->id`) is an array, not a single value. If you want help, you need to show where you're calling `new CustomerExport(...)`; that `...` is what `$id` becomes.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getColumnListing()` to get columns list of specific schema in laravel, It's an alternate way of `getAttributes()`

```
use Schema;

$attributes = Schema::getColumnListing((new CustomerModel)->getTable());
```

Comment: if you wanted to use `getColumnListing` you don't need to find the model first, you just need an instance so you can get it's table name ... `Schema::getColumnListing((new CustomerModel)->getTable())`